# What's a simple way to generate a random bool in C?

Tags: c, random

I want to generate a random boolean for use in a game, so it does not need to be cryptographically secure. I will use `stdbool.h` in my code, and I have also done `#include <stdlib.h>`. Preferably, it should be very fast (as I will be generating many of them), and it should be able to be done in C89 (just preference). I am not interested at all in doing this in C++.

Here are some of the ways I've come up with:

- read from /dev/urandom, filter out single digits and >5 = true, <5 = false.
- keep calling rand() and filter out low/high values.

Comment: If you call `rand`, you can perform `% 2` on the result to get a 0 or 1.

Comment: `> 5` = true, `< 5` = false means you'll get true most of the time, unless you extract only 3 bits from `/dev/urandom` stream, then you'll get false most of the time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just call `rand()` and get the LSB of its return value.

```
bool randbool = rand() & 1;
```

Remember to call `srand()` at the beginning.

Comment: Same result, but `% 2` may be a little clearer (i.e. self documenting).

Comment: I think `& 1` may generate more efficient code (when not optimized)

Comment: A good optimising compiler will make the most efficient code regardless which one you use. Better to program for readability and clarity than trying to hand optimise.

Comment: This is an antipattern because the low order bit generated by rand may not be very random. Its better to compare with `RAND_MAX/2`. (See the Notes section in the manpage http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html)

Comment: @aterjuice, Fiddling Bits  `&1` and `%2` are not functional equivalent with an `int` argument.  Best to use `rand() & 1` here.

Comment: This is a very bad practice. The implementation of rand() rely on linear congruential generators (LCGs), which are notoriously problematic pseudo-random number generators. They lack randomness at lower bits of the output. You should at least take the most significant bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257035/918959

Comment: It's random enough for many purposes, running INT_MAX times, it's fairly balanced also: zero: 1073738760 one: 1073744887

Answer (score 1):

If you have `RDRAND` instruction set on a x86_64 CPU:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cstdint>
...
bool randBool() {
  uint64_t val;
  if(!_rdseed64_step(&val)) {
    printf("Error generating hardware random value\n");
  }
  return bool(val&1);
}
```

However, this wastes 63 out of 64 pseudo-random bits generated. If you need more speed, call `_rdseed64_step()` once in 64 random bit generations, but change the bit tested in each generation: `val&(1<<0)` , `val & (1<<1)`, `val & (1<<2)`, `val & (1<<3)`, ... , `val & (1<<i)`, ..., `val & (1<<63)` .