# How to choose between two values in a random way?

Tags: c, random, numbers

I am trying to choose one of two numbers randomly: `2` or `-2`. Is there a way to do it? I am trying to implement an algorithm to create a maze.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060893/whats-a-simple-way-to-generate-a-random-bool-in-c

Answer (score 2):

You have [`rand()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) from the C standard library, which returns a pseudo-random integer in the range [0, `RAND_MAX`]. You can use this function and choose one of the two numbers checking if the value returned is above or below `RAND_MAX/2`.

First, use [`srand()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) to initialize the pseudo-random number generator with some seed. It's common to use [`time()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) to do this as it returns a different value each time.

```
srand(time(NULL));

int rnd = rand();
int result = (rnd > RAND_MAX/2) ? 2 : -2;
```

Alternatively you could use the least significant bit of the value returned by `rand()`, as suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060893/whats-a-simple-way-to-generate-a-random-bool-in-c), since half the values returned are odd and half are even:

```
int result = (rnd & 1) ? 2 : -2;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, my favorite is:

```
a + rand() % 2 * (b - a);
```

but it **isn't clear** what does it do and it **doesn't contribute on efficiency** either (well if you would make it into a macro/inline function and never used with variables, modern compilers should evaluate the numbers at the compile-time), so the most elegant way to do this would be to use some kind of condition, here's an example with ternary operator:

```
(rand() % 2)? a: b;
```

BTW: There are many ways to chose between 0/1, I used rand()%2 because it's most the used technique,
but if you happened to be doing this for 6502 architecture where there's no modulo/division you can do it with bitwise-and operator like this *rand() & ANY_POWER_OF_TWO* or like this *rand() > HALF_MAX_RAND*

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. It uses bitwise operations to generate either `2` or `-2` without branching:

```
-((rand() & 1) << 2) + 2
```

I note that **you should use `srand()` to seed the random number generator before using it**; I commonly use `srand(time(NULL))`.

Step-by-step:

- `(rand() & 1)` generates a random number: either `0` or `1`.
- `<< 2` multiplies the previous result by `4`, and the `-` in front of `-((rand() & 1) << 2)` negates that, so the result is either `0` or `-4`.
- `+ 2` adds `2`, so the result is either `2` or `-2`.

If you'd like to see a more arithmetic-like approach that may be easier to follow, here it is:

```
rand % 2 * -4 + 2
```